# import from web api to excel fast

Tags: json, xml, excel, asp.net-web-api

I have a web api which can return json or xml. What is the best way(quickest) to import the data returned from web api into excel?

The number of records returned from API is around 50000. I did a quick test using a xml local file and tried to import it into excel and it takes over 5 min. I am looking for a faster way. I also tried to import the local XML file using VBA with same performance.

The xml file used had just elements, no attributes.

```
   <records>
     <record>
       <field1>1</field1>
       <field2>Name</field2>
     </record>
     <record>
       <field1>2</field1>
       <field2>Nome</field2>
     </record>
    </records>
```

As a clarification, the data in excel is used to generate lots of charts/reports.

Is there a way to have excel parse XML data (or JSON) in a faster way ? If I convert the XML to use attributes(I know it has a smaller footprint) will it help?

Comment: Can the WebApi just return an excel file instead? What is creating the excel file? Another c# application?

Comment: The excel file is not created over and over again.,.only it's master data is to be refreshed. The excel has one sheet with master data which feeds the other sheets where the charts and summary reports are.. The idea is to have the raw data refreshed on demand by the web service...not to create a new excel file.

Comment: I would look at [openxml](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff478153.aspx). While I haven't encountered your exact scenario, I know that I'm able to create a new excel sheet with ~10,000 rows using it in around 3 seconds.

Comment: Exactly how did you perform the test import ?

Comment: From  excel 2013 -> Data -> Data from other sources -> From XML Data Import I selected the local XML File. I also did the import from Developer -> Import XML with the same performance.